# previous objects of google Maps v2 android are not being removed

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

[image]

As we seen in above diagram, This is related to fragments and Maps.

If we click on left side fragment, The corresponding details are shown in detailview and Map view Which are in tabhost (Right side Fragment). In the mapview we shown markers for particular data.

Problem : If we click on another item on left fragment, the right side fragment should be replaced with new details. I was able to do it.**But,the older objects of Map are still in memory.****

and some times showing, due to **java.lang.ref.FinalizerRefernce**

I examined with eclipse MAT. The screen shots are also attached below.

[image]

[image]

**Every time when reloads, heap memory consumption is increasing..**

And I followed the map lifecycle. During destroying of frament, I added the code like..

mapView.onDestroy() also.

Can anybody tell  me where i was doing wrong?

Thanks Inadvance.